# Checking only syntax of string to be evaled, not evaluate in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, eval

As title mentions, I need to let users input some Ruby script code and my script will store them for later call. How can I check the user input syntax without actually evaluating?

Comment: You're looking for the programatic equivalent of `ruby -c`, which I don't think exists in the Ruby standard library.

Comment: Would `ruby -c fname_prefix.rb` with a backtick ` at each end meet your needs?

Comment: `Proc.new` cannot be used. `String#to_proc` doesn't exist. `String#to_sym.to_proc` is useless. Parsing the source code manually is likely going to be difficult (though `case /.../` is going to be helpful if you do decide to write an LL(1) parser). Ruby is LL(1), so it's not impossible, however. Just a lot of coding.

Comment: @CarySwoveland good idea - but can you rely on the `ruby` command being present in the shell and you having a write access somewhere?

Comment: @JanDvorak Good point. Also, I forgot quotes around the filename.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't have the `ruby` command. I do have `jruby`, but what else did we forget? And calling `$0` indiscriminately is definitely a bad idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def correct_syntax? code
  stderr = $stderr
  $stderr.reopen(IO::NULL)
  RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile(code)
  true
rescue Exception
  false
ensure
  $stderr.reopen(stderr)
end

correct_syntax?("def foo; end") # => true
correct_syntax?("foo") # => true
correct_syntax?("def foo; en")  # => false
correct_syntax?("foo bar") # => false
```

Comment: You should check for Ruby 2.0: [RubyVM::InstructionSequence](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html).